# decrease variable by button click C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I want to decrease a value by clicking a button, but it does not stay at and turns back to the value at the beginning,
here is my code, what should I add or change can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot

```
public class LifeShow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Life; //where the variable will be decreased from
        
    public int Lifevalue;
    public string text;
    public Button returns;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Lifevalue = 1;

        Life.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Life : " + Lifevalue;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    // clicking the button and the lifevalue variable decreases
    void Update()
    {
        Button btn = returns.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);



        void TaskOnClick()
        {
            Lifevalue-- ;

            Life.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Life : " + Lifevalue;

            
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add description near the variables in the code but I am not sure about how it should be as I am new to csharp and to the forum :/

Comment: Are you sure you want to `btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick)` for _every single frame_? Usually you'd register the event handler _once_.

Comment: You should move **TaskOnClick** function to outside of update function. Beside you don't need update just for this function. Create **TaskOnClick** function as seperate and first 2 lines of update function should be in inside of start function. That should work.

Comment: I want that everytime if there is a life value greater than 0, to decrease on button click, should I use something else for the button click ?

Comment: Yes I am pretty new to Csharp, I am trying to learn. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is change the local method `void TaskOnClick()` to a public method by putting it outside update and using `public` keyword and you can add OnClick in unity
[image: OnClick Image]

now hit the '+' button and drag and drop your object that script attached to. You can then find as this
[image: Functions in OnClick of unity]

choose your function and you are ready. You don't need to do this by script.
If you want to restrict it to not go below 0 you can add a If condition in script

```
if(LifeValue > 0)
{
  LifeValue--;
  // showing text
}
```

It will prevent to go below 0.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it really works but my problem is when I go back to the start scene the life value returns to 1 instead of 0 I thought I should update it.

Comment: I want the integer to stay as same when the button is pressed, when I press the button it changes the integer but then it returns to the value at the beginning so it is not decreasing.

Comment: It can cause you restarted scene or reloading. Yeah if you restarted it will be reset because it isn't saving

Answer (score 0):

- OnClick `+` to add listener
- Drag listener object to slot (Life)
- Choice function from Life script (Modify)
- Set argument value `1` / `-1` / `-99`

[image]

[image]

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Life : MonoBehaviour {

    public event System.Action<int> Changed; // event with INT attribute
    private int _amouth;

    public int Amouth { // this in property
        get => _amouth;
        // when you set Amouth, then change _amouth and invoke "Changed" event
        set {
            if (_amouth != value) {
                _amouth = value;
                Changed?.Invoke(_amouth);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Start () {
        Amouth = 1;
    }

    public void Modify (int number) {
        Amouth += number;
    }
}
```

---

[image]

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]

public class LifeView : MonoBehaviour { // Add Component to text object

    [SerializeField] private Life _life; // set on inspector window
    private Text _text;

    public int LineAmouth { get; private set; }

    private void OnEnable () {
        _text = GetComponent<Text>();
        UpdateText(_life.Amouth);
        _life.Changed += UpdateText; // subscribes to Life event 
    }

    private void OnDisable () {
        _life.Changed -= UpdateText;
    }

    private void UpdateText (int amouth) {
        _text.text = "Life : "+amouth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really an expert of Mono but, first of all it seems that you are attaching an event handler on every frame, which is not good. The code should be:

```
public class LifeShow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Life; //where the variable will be decreased from
        
    public int Lifevalue;
    public string text;
    public Button returns;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Lifevalue = 1;

        Life.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Life : " + Lifevalue;
        Button btn = returns.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        Lifevalue-- ;
        Life.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Life : " + Lifevalue;
    }
}
```

Second, it is pretty unclear what's the difference between Lifevalue and the Life GameObject, can you tell?

EDIT: As someone stated in the comments this code is not really enough to give good hints, could you show the Life object's code? That would be pretty helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try for it, life gameobject is a text object and lifevalue is the variable that I want to be appeared near the next

Comment: Lifevalue is a integer and Life is a gameobject.

Comment: Easy, i think i see it now. Again, not an expert of Mono but where is the "returns" field initialized? You call returns.GetComponent<Button>(), doesn't this throw an exception (null) ?

Comment: @I-am-developer-9 Well that is pretty clear :) I just don't know what the Life object does / is there for

Comment: He used it to change the text of Text component of Life object @Pit

Comment: @I-am-developer-9 Alrighty, I think it's not clear why I'm asking that. Why is there a "text" field in the LifeShow object and is never used ? Does the Life object have a int property called Lifevalue ? if yes, why replicate it in the LifeShow object? Where is the returns field initialized in the LifeShow object ? It just seems that he's creating 2 different object when you could actually do this with only one. That's the sense of my question, just trying to understand the OP's code :)

Comment: Text component is attached to Life object. He is showing user how many life value left. So he is changing life value Text shower. He can either use public Text instead of public GameObject with UnityEngine.UI. He isn't creating 2 object. He is actually getting the component of Life game object. They aren't 2 object.

Comment: @I-am-developer-9 Ok, but still, we need to see the Life object's code, or at least, I do need.